# Need diagnostic tips for ancient Sanwa YX-360TRe

Tags: analog, meter

I need to fix my sentimental value Sanwa YX-360TRe analog meter. It was bought in 1995, slightly used. It can correctly give DC voltage reading. The problem is, it cannot zero-ohm adjust in all ranges, despite using fresh new batteries (9V and two AAA). When short probes, the needle very slightly moves at all. I open it up and here is picture [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zRkhdHk0iu-kRXL_B6U7-ol6n3AmYyYi). I measured each resistors using my Fluke 17B+ DMM and the measured values are [here](https://gist.github.com/typelogic/0ccd379023bfa87ab6887ba92db10586). I suspect the culprit is `C2` because I couldn't get a reading on this one. But I'm not sure because it's in-circuit. I searched far and wide, and could not find the schematic of this particular model. I am still waiting my order of the suspected `C2` brown ceramic capacitor which is marked `F 473Z` to arrive. I also cleaned-up with vinegar+salt solution the greenish copper wire as that copper wire no longer beeps when I touch it with my Fluke 17B+ probes. Now that it is clean, it beeps. I also suspect that is the culprit. For the mean time, I appreciate any comments or have this specific model.

Comment: C2 won’t disable the R scale, so check the wipers for corrosion or loose contact force. The schematic exists on the web

Comment: https://www.eserviceinfo.com/download.php?downloadstart=1&fileid=59444. This has everything

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a very standard D'Arsonval analog meter. It reads **full-scale** when 50 uA flows through the movement's coil. This corresponds to **0 ohms**.

- For measuring large-value resistors, the 9V battery would be used to power the current source, quite likely in series with the two 1.5v AAA cells.
- For measuring on lowest ohm scales, the two series-connected 1.5V AAA cells would be used.

It is possible that those two voltage sources are used in series (total of 12v) on the x10k ohm scale.

When measuring ohms, **half-scale** is "20". So when measuring on the x10k scale, a current of 25 uA would flow through the meter movement. A 200k test resistor would result in 25 uA. If we neglect the resistance of the wire coil of the D'Arsonval movement and assume that the 9V + 3V battery is used as the source, the ohm circuit would be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHK2VM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you get no deflection of the meter's needle, chances are that the current path is broken somewhere. The schematic shown above is simplified, and doesn't show the resistors used on the other ohm scales of x1k, x10, x1.
 Since the batteries are connected off-board with flying wires, chances are that their contacts are faulty. The other culprit could be the selector scale rotary switch.

It is unlikely that the internal resistors used to measure ohms are faulty - they are fairly large-value and not likely to burn up.

Comment: ++1 "The other culprit could be the selector scale rotary switch." I had this with an anlog multimeter. Careful cleaning got it back. This one is 26 years old, maybe stored for a lot of that time ("slightly used").